Adding new items does not show even its added but seems the font is white or something but chaning fonts didn't solve it
enter image description hereAfter adding items doesn't show at simulator even the data added to DB, items should show in simulator with CoreData even it was showing perfectly before with standard plist using users default, kindly find below AppDelegate.swift file also ViewController.swift file
enter image description here
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Destini
//
//  Created by Philipp Muellauer on 01/09/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 London App Brewery. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}







//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Todoey
//
//  Created by Philipp Muellauer on 02/12/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 App Brewery. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ToDoListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var itemArray = [Item]()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask))
        loadItems()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Table DatatSource Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return itemArray.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)
        
       // cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].titile
        
        //Ternary Operator
        // Value = condtion ? valutIFTure: ValueIFFalse
        cell.accessoryType = itemArray[indexPath.row].done ? .checkmark : .none
//        if itemArray[indexPath.row].done == true {
//            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
//        } else {
//            cell.accessoryType = .none
//        }

        return cell
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Table Vieww Delegate Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        itemArray[indexPath.row].done = !itemArray[indexPath.row].done
//        context.delete(itemArray[indexPath.row])
//        itemArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        saveItem()
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
 
    //MARK: - Add New Item
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var textField = UITextField()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Todoay Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "creat new item"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in
            //What will happen once the user clickes the add Item button on UIAlert
            let newItem = Item(context: self.context)
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            newItem.done = false
            self.itemArray.append(newItem)
            print(newItem)
            self.saveItem()
        }
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Model MOnpoulation Method
    func saveItem() {
        do {
            try context.save()
        }catch {
            print("Error saveing econtext \(error)")
        }
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func loadItems(){
       
        let request = Item.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
           itemArray = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetch datat form loatItem() \(error)")
        }
        
    }
     
    }




appending core data object to array is not possible. please remove self.itemArray.append(newItem). After saving you should refetch so please add loadItems() before self.tableView.reloadData()

unfortunately the same as the attached image it seems the data added but like the font is white or something I tried to change font but the same

and in func cellForRowAt you should assign todo title to cell label

i didn't notice i comment that line, thanks a lot for your help and time and consideration
